Plotting graph of equation of state parameter vs redshift
How to plot the graph of omega_D vs 1+z using mathematica for the equation: omega_D=(delta-1)/((2-delta)Omega_D-1)?
where delta = {1.4,1.5,1.7} and Omega_D(z=0)=0.70
please see fig 1 in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2018.04.001

Your equation does not involve z. How does z enter into the relationship?

What have you tried so far? Your post lack details and a code.

You need to use Eq. 17
$$
\Omega_D(1-\Omega_D)^{1-\delta} = C(1+z)^{3(1-d)}
$$
together with Eq. 14:
$$
\omega_d = \frac{\delta -1}{(2-\delta)\Omega_d - 1}
$$
To reproduce Fig 1.
I just use FindRoot to numerically solve Eq. 17.
Note I do not plot all the way to z+1 = 0, as FindRoot has some issues there and starts to explode.
(*definitions*)
Ωd[0] = 0.7;
cConst[δ_] = (Ωd[0] (1 - Ωd[0])^(
   1 - δ))/(1 + 0)^(3 (1 - δ));
Ωd[z_, δ_] := 
 om /. FindRoot[
   om (1 - om)^(1 - δ) == 
    cConst[δ] (1 + z)^(
     3 (1 - δ)), {om, Ωd[0]}]
ωd[z_, δ_] := (δ - 
  1)/((2 - δ) Ωd[z, δ] - 1)

(*plotting*)

deltaList = {1.4, 1.5, 1.7};
(*z-1 shift so we can plot z+1 on x-axis*)
plotFuns := ωd[z - 1, #] & /@ deltaList;
plot = Plot[plotFuns, {z, 0.06, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, deltaList, LegendFunction -> Framed, 
     LegendLabel -> "δ"], {Left, Top}], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Darker@Yellow}, Green, {Dashed, Blue}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"z+1", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(d\)]\)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black , Medium]]



Thank you so much, ydd.
